# Customizing Button Commands in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I've recently started learning how to use Tkinter. I'm working on the front-end for a small project to design an Enigma Machine, and a part of it involves creating a keyboard-like layout of buttons to simulate the plugboard. When clicking one button, I want it to go to a method I've created to handle all button presses and tell the method which letter the button corresponds to, and act accordingly. The main task right now is to make it so that pressing one button and then pressing another button after that draws a line between both buttons.

What I've added below is a scuffed version of the actual program to cut out repeated code like the button declarations.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Steckerbrett:
    root = Tk()

    frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
    frm.grid(row=0, column=0)
    ttk.Label(frm, text="Enigma Machine").grid(column=0, row=0)
    ttk.Label(frm, text="Steckerbrett").grid(column=0, row=1)
    ttk.Label(frm, text="").grid(column=0, row=2)

    # plugboard keys row 1
    frm1 = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
    frm1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ttk.Button(frm1, text="Q", command=connection).grid(column=0, row=0)
    ttk.Button(frm1, text="W", command=connection).grid(column=1, row=0)
    # i have declarations like this for all 26 letters

    root.mainloop()
    
    def connection(self, letter):
        ttk.Label(self.frm, text=letter).grid(column=0, row=2)


sb = Steckerbrett()
```

The issue here is that since 'command' doesn't allow entering a function with arguments, I can't pass the letter to the function, and I can not make a custom method for every single button, because I would need to process first button presses and second button presses differently to make the connections. Is there a way to use a single function in the command but customize it to each button? Alternatively, if there isn't, are there any other solutions I can try? I am willing to try using other graphics packages as well.

Comment: You can use *lambda*: `command=lambda: connection(...)`.  However I would suggest you to go through tutorials on Python OOP because you have used class in a wrong way.  Note that even without the line `sb = Steckerbrett()`, the tkinter window will still be shown.

Comment: I'm still getting used to moving to Python from Java, didn't know that it was utilized differently. I'll make sure to do that.
To add on to the solution, I've removed the class structure entirely and it runs fine, but now I get an error saying TypeError: connection() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
EDIT: I fixed it by moving the method's code above the rest of the code. Wish Python had forward declaration, but well